# Bundler claims that it is installing pg but later complains that it can't install it (RHEL7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rhel7

Do you know why bundler would claim that it’s installing the pg gem and then afterward complain that it can’t compile it?  It indicates that gems are not installed in parallel, but then goes on to attempt to install pg, produces no errors, goes to install rmagick, and then produces an error for pg.

When I look in the Gemfile rmagick is listed before pg... very confused.

```
Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe, so your gems will be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
Using rake 11.3.0
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.9.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using pkg-config 1.1.7
Using rack 1.6.4
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 6.0.3
Using addressable 2.4.0
Using bundler 1.13.2
Using coderay 1.1.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Using htmlentities 4.3.1
Using thor 0.19.1
Using mimemagic 0.3.2
Using net-ldap 0.12.1
Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions
Using ruby-openid 2.3.0
Using rbpdf-font 1.19.0
Using redcarpet 3.3.4
Using request_store 1.0.5
Installing rmagick 2.16.0 with native extensions
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Installing nokogiri 1.6.8 with native extensions
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using mime-types 3.1
Using css_parser 1.3.7
Using sprockets 3.7.0
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/
/usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:519:in `try_link0'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:534:in `try_link'
    from extconf.rb:36:in `'


Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/.gem/ruby/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /tmp/.gem/ruby/gems/pg-0.18.4/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: In saying it's installing it - it's telling you that this is what it is going to try installing today... not that it has successfully installed it. In order to fix this problem, google this error: `extconf.rb failed` and "pg gem" (the issue is this part: "You have to install development tools first.")

Comment: So do you mean that all of the lines after "Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions" have to do with creating the pg gem?  Why would rmagick have to be installed to install the pg gem?  It specifically indicates that it is not installing things in parallel.

Comment: it doesn't... as I said, the words `Installing <gemname>` do not mean "I have just installed the gem called `gemname`" - they are merely saying "during this bundle process, I will be installing the gem called `gemname`"... bundler looks through your Gemfile to find all the gems that need installing - regardless of whether they are listed by themselves or dependencies of one another... and lists all of the ones that need installing as `installing...`  There is likely no connection at all between `pg` and `rmagick` except that neither has yet been installed.

Comment: Of course "Installing" doesn't mean "I have just installed" but I've run bundler for this Gemfile multiple times, resolving dependencies as I go along, and it never has told me everything it's going to install first.  It always says "Installing...", installs the package, and goes onto the next package.  Anyway, it's just an output oddity--I can't do a 'gem install pg -v 1.18.4' either.  I thought it would be a way for me to figure out maybe why I couldn't install it.  But I suppose this isn't a good question.

Comment: Should I just delete this question and chalk it up to me being super confused and not knowing what I'm talking about?  I looked at the Gemfile and rmagick is listed before pg.  So I clearly don't understand how this works.

Comment: heh - confusion is pretty typical surrounding starting out with gemfiles :) The pg thing is still definitely something you need fixing... have a go at that and we can continue this question assuming that's all that need solving :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124837/discussion-between-angelo-and-taryn-east).

Comment: Sorry I have work that I'm doing in between stopping by... no time for a long chat :(

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have PostgreSQL installed. It occurred to me as well on macOS. I simply did `brew install postgresql` and ran `bundle` again. If you're on any other OS you need to install PostgreSQL accordingly.
What this will do is install all the missing libraries required by the gem.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you do not have installed postgresql software itself on to your machine.
That's why when you are trying to install the gem, it can not find the `executable` of the postgresql software.Hence bundler is failing to install the gem. 
To install postgresql on your machine

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib #If you are on linux(ubuntu).

brew install postgresql #If you are on mac
```

Hope you've got your answer. Enjoy